# Incremental data in yii CListView

Tags: listview, yii

I'm wondering whether it's possible to have an incremental variable through a CListView widget? For example I want the first item rendered to contain a param with the value 0, the second item to contain a param with the value 1, the third item to contain a param with the value 2... and so on...

Unfortunately I can't use the item's ID as a unique identifier, what I'm looking for needs to be an incremental value from the first item to the last.

I'm not sure if it's possible to send a dynamic param through something like the `viewData` property, so that each item rendered has a unique value for a given param?

From what I can see the only unique data each rendered item in the list can have is the data model sent through the `dataprovider` property? Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$index` variable in the `CListView.iteView` partial. Take a look to the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView#itemView-detail):

*$index: refers to the zero-based index of the data item currently being rendered.*

Comment: perfect! Thanks, +1... why did't I see that! Yii never stops surprising me with its nifty little features heh